# Disable laptop speaker but allow external plug-in device

Tags: windows-vista, audio

How can I disable the speaker of my laptop, without disabling possible sound output by external speakers (or headphones)?

I listen to music via my headphones while in library, but I do not want any (loud and disturbing) sound output in case my headphones plug-off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go to **sound option** under **control panel**.

From there, under playback, right click on the speaker icon and disable it.

[image: Sound option in control panel]

If this does not work for you then please share some more info related to Laptop model number.

Comment: Thank you. However, it seems my system does not discriminate between the built-in laptop speakers and the headphone slot. They are one and the same in the menu. I wonder whether a driver update may help.

Comment: yea you can try to update the latest driver or may be you can find the solution om the software ,manager  just like realtek sound manager or sound Max. Check your control  panel for these items may be those can help you to setup proper device output.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this function has already been implemented in Vista, but from 7 onwards the system saves the state for plugged-in or -out. So, plug-out the headphones and mute. Then, when you connect them, sound should become enabled. When you unplug, it should automatically go back to silence.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!